# vscode format reactnative code and eslint conflict

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

Create project：

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
```

code:

```js
import {createDrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
```

Press: `Shift + Alt + F`

code:

```js
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
```

error message:

```
Replace `·createDrawerNavigator·` with `createDrawerNavigator`eslint(prettier/prettier)
```

How do i configure?

Comment: ok!  `ext install esbenp.prettier-vscode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run  `ext install esbenp.prettier-vscode`